# macOS Catalina beachball appears when I use TextEdit or Preview apps

Tags: macos, catalina, preview, performance, textedit

I have a MacBook with macOS Catalina 10.15.3 installed.

I'm now noticing that whenever I open an image file with the Preview app, a beachball appears right about when I quit the app.

Also, a beachball appears whenever I open a text file using the TextEdit app.

Is there any way I can reset things to fix these problems?

Comment: Have you done SMC reset, NVRAM reset to see how it goes. It doesn't hamper doing it but saw in many forums where they recommend for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I did some more Google searching, and so the answer for this bug I was facing is to Disable the "Dropbox Finder Extensions" in the "Extensions" section in System Preference.

It seems the Finder features of Dropbox (like green dot next to filename in finder etc.) was causing beachballs in using TextEdit & Preview. Now it's been fixed for me.

Since it's a bug, I hope Dropbox & Apple will fix it.

Comment: OMG, this has been plaguing me for months! I was beginning to think it was a macOS bug! Finally an answer with the culprit! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the Activity Monitor app `/Applications/Utilities`, and see if anything is using large amounts of CPU, memory or Energy while this is happening.

Make sure you're viewing "All Processes" (select under the "View" menu).

Comment: It seems the WindowsServer process is taking about 20% of cpu.. I reset smc and nvram but still problem with Preview app whenever I open an image file.

Comment: What model of MacBook is this, exactly? Do you notice the beachball with any other apps?

Comment: It's a 2014 Macbook pro. I see beachball with 2 apps mostly - Textedit & Preview. Is there anyway to reset their plist files or something similar?